# Having trouble with KOPS and Traefik ingress controller installation

Tags: kubernetes, kops, aws-elb

I am new to kubernetes and have installed KOPS and now I want to use traefik as a ingress controller and cant get through it, I have a domain "xyz.com" and nameserver on cloudflare. I tried to create a "CNAME" record with my domain with ELB of aws which I get after deploying all files but it didn't worked and I don't want to use route53. I actually can't get proper guidance regarding this. Have gone through the documentation but somewhere got an idea but not working. Can anyone tell me somewhere like step wise, I will be very grateful.

Comment: So you installed Traefik using the Helm chart (or otherwise the Deployment+Service style)?

Comment: @coderanger yes, Deployment + service style

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment, that is correct. You would set your DNS for all relevant domains to CNAME to the ELB generated for the Traefik Service.